# SQL Group rows based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Example Address Table

```
ID, EmployeeID, Address

1, 100, TownA
2, 200, TownA
3, 300, TownB
```

How can i return a count of all employess for each unique address?

e.g

```
EmployeeCount, Address

2 TownA
1, TownB
```

Comment: use group by and count(column)

Comment: `SELECT count(ID) as EmployeeCount, Address FROM tblAddress group by Address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something along the lines of this.

```
SELECT count(EmployeeID) as EmployeeCount, Address FROM table GROUP BY Address
```

Comment: i asked the wrong question, instead of EmployeeId's i had a column of binaries, and wanted to sum instead of count, but your answer is correct  for above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple grouping

```
SELECT Count(*) EmployeeCount, Address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Address
```